# Does compressing files in a docker image speed up pulling it?

Tags: docker

I have a file that's 3GB compressed, 10GB uncompressed.

Is it faster to pull an image containing only that file if the file is compressed? Or are docker images compressed already, such that compressing it won't make a difference?

Comment: Docker image layers are already compressed, so compressing the file does not make a difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

docker images are compressed by default. you will notice when running `docker pull`, where it will download the needed images\layers and then extract\decompress them.

there is no need for you to compress the files within your docker images.

from the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/#extended-description):

> Progress bars are shown during docker push, which show the uncompressed size. The actual amount of data that’s pushed will be compressed before sending, so the uploaded size will not be reflected by the progress bar.

Comment: Thanks. Are you confident this i how it works in practice? If I'm seeing a large difference between the two images in "Size", does that mean the compression isn't working? One is 3.5GB and one is 12GB. Or are those uncompressed sizes? I also see "Download... 12.5GB" when pulling.

Comment: @Maximilian: absolutely sure. i've updated my answer with the official documentation. if it answered you question, please accept the answer :)

Comment: Docker's compression I think uses gzip while you could get much better compression ratios using better compression algos like lzma / lz4. So there would potentially be a benefit in compressing things yourself.